# Discordpy ctx send <discord.ext.commands.context.Context object at someid> instead of the actual command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a centralized error missing argument on my discord bot, but it didn't work as I expected , this is the code

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f"Se necesitan argumentos `!help  {ctx}` para verlos")
```

In my mind this should look like this

> Se necesitan argumentos !help  command para verlos

but it turned out looking like this

> Se necesitan argumentos !help <discord.ext.commands.context.Context object at 0x7fba169585b0> para verlos

How can can I make that it looks like the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know the command which triggered the error if its a centralized error handler. Inform the user by putting `<command_name>` as a part of the string

Here's an example:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArguments):
      await ctx.send('Se necesitan argumentos !help <command> para verlos')
```

<command> is part of the string. This way you are informing the user to pass a `command` argument, or else, the command will not work.